# Is there a difference between C: and C:\ in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, directory

I am writing a spreadsheet that has paths to files.
It will be used in a custom script with some not-well-known software that the company I work at uses. The custom script will read the column in the spreadsheet that has the path + file, in order to find a file residing at that location.

The spreadsheet has path+file entries such as

> C:3.jpg

but, usually, in real life, I see a path+file written like this:

> C:\3.jpg

Does it matter which way it is written?

Comment: also, this is only slightly related and maybe inappropriate to ask here, but how can i search for questions with "c:\" etc in the search? is it even possible? when i tried to search for this, i got lots of "c vs c++" answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The first means *3.jpg in whatever the current directory is on drive C*, while the second means *3.jpg in the root directory of drive C*.

In other words, if you're at a command prompt:

```
C:\Temp>
```

then `C:3.jpg` would refer to `C:\Temp\3.jpg`, while at the prompt

```
C:\Users\silph>
```

referring to `C:3.jpg` would be `C:\Users\silph\3.jpg`.

On the other hand, at the same two prompts (`C:\Temp>` and `C:\Users\silph>`), referring to `C:\3.jpg` would always refer to the same 3.jpg located in the root of drive C:.

Comment: it seems that `C:3.jpg` is very related to using a relative path, `.\3.jpg`. This gets me thinking, if my current directory is on the D drive instead (as in `D:\happy\day\ ` ), what does `C:3.jpg` mean?

Comment: It means it will open the 3.jpg file in the current directory on **C**, just as I said previously. *C:* always refers to the C drive.

Comment: maybe my confusion is what a "current directory" is. in Windows, does the "current directory" include the drive letter? if this is the case, what does it mean to "open the 3.jpg file in the current directory on C" if the current directory is in the D drive instead of in the C drive?

Comment: No, it's not the *current directory on the D drive* if you specify C:. Each drive has a current directory (the directory that is currently active). Test for yourself if you have a C: and D: drive. Open a command window, which will leave you in C:\Users\silph (replace with your actual user name). Type D: and hit Enter. You'll be in D:\. The current directory on D: is the root. Type `dir C:` (no slash) and hit Enter, and you'll get a directory of the current directory on C: (your user directory).